# How to create a release number in Jenkins from a Git tag?

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

How can I set the version of a Jenkins build based on a Git tag?

What I am currently doing:

1. Use the Maven versions plugin to set the release version of the current build from the Jenkins build number, e.g. newVersion=1.1.$BUILD_NUMBER
2. Build and deploy the project using Maven
3. Use Git Publisher to tag the build in Git using the build number, e.g. MYPROJECT_BUILD-1.1.$BUILD_NUMBER

What I would like to do: Instead of using the Jenkins BUILD_NUMBER, I would like to extract the last build number from the Git tag and increment it

1. Get the latest tag from Git that matches a given pattern, such as MYPROJECT_BUILD-.*
2. Extract the build number from the tag and increment it
3. Build and deploy the project using Maven
4. Use Git Publisher to tag the build in Git using the incremented build number, e.g. MYPROJECT_BUILD-1.1.124

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't really know about Maven. Is there any specific reason why Git should drive the numbering?

Maven is IMHO the better choice. It knows about your source control (if you have configured `<scm>` correctly) and knows what the version is and if it's a release or a snapshot.

With the combination of Maven + Git + Jenkins we are very happy with the [Release plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Release+Plugin): It takes your snapshot, does a Maven release and tags it in Git, and commits the change to the next snapshot (you define that version number).

Comment: I want to avoid picking the version number manually. The build system should increment the version number from the last build. Since I am tagging the releases in Git with the version number anyway, I thought it would make a lot of sense to use that tag to determine the next version number.

Comment: Th normal version format is <major>.<minor>.<patch>. How should the system do a sensible version management on its own? And since Git doesn't know about Maven snapshots and releases, this won't work well

Comment: Of course, Git doesn't need to know anything about Maven snapshots and releases. It is only used to store the tags. Something like `git describe --tags --abbrev=0 --match 'MYPROJECT*'` would deliver the latest tag. Then I would parse the tag, increment the patch-number of the version and use that for the current build. If I need to increment the major-number or minor-number, which doesn't happen frequently, I would do this manually.

Comment: You could do this with a shell script, but it sounds pretty hackish to me (get the latest tag, check if it's different from the Maven version, if yes trigger a new release,...). If you aren't releasing multiple times a week I'm not sure if that's worth the trouble

Comment: We are releasing multiple times a week and the releases can be triggered by different people. Asking them to figure out the next release number manually wouldn´t be a good idea.